# Invert Concordance Using Java

Tags: java, set, symbol-table

today I'm working with a client that creates a concordance from a text file using Java. All I need to do is invert the concordance to essentially recreate the text from start to finish. Now, the issue I seem to be having is where to start and how to do each step. As of now I have tried to create an array of words and iterate through my symbol table and assign each key to the array. Then I end up getting just a list of words from the concordance. For some reason this problem makes me feel very stupid because it seems like it should be a simple solution. I can't seem to think of any valid ideas to get me started with recreating the story. I have included the source here:

```
public class InvertedConcordance {

public static ST<String, SET<Integer>> createConcordance (String[] words) {
    ST<String, SET<Integer>> st = new ST<String, SET<Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        String s = words[i];
        if (!st.contains(s)) {
            st.put(s, new SET<Integer>());
        }
        SET<Integer> set = st.get(s);
        set.add(i);
    }
    return st;
}
public static String[] invertConcordance (ST<String, SET<Integer>> st) {

 //This is what I have so far
//Here is what I have that doesnt work
for(String key : st.keys())
{
inv[i++] = key;
}
for(int z = 0; z< inv.length; z++)
{
System.out.println(inv[z]);
}


 String[]inv = new String[st.size()];

    return inv;
}
private static void saveWords (String fileName, String[] words) {
    int MAX_LENGTH = 70;
    Out out = new Out (fileName);
    int length = 0;
    for (String word : words) {
        length += word.length ();
        if (length > MAX_LENGTH) {
            out.println ();
            length = word.length ();
        }
        out.print (word);
        out.print (" ");
        length++;
    }
    out.close ();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "data/tale.txt";
    In in = new In (fileName);
    String[] words = in.readAll().split("\\s+");

    ST<String, SET<Integer>> st = createConcordance (words);
    StdOut.println("Finished building concordance");

    // write to a file and read back in (to check that serialization works)
    //serialize ("data/concordance-tale.txt", st);
    //st = deserialize ("data/concordance-tale.txt");

    words = invertConcordance (st);
    saveWords ("data/reconstructed-tale.txt", words);
}
```

}

Comment: What is "concordance"? I tried to google it, but found nothing relevant.

Comment: @MightyPork The first line in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordance) entry seems to be what the OP is talking about.

Comment: Basically it is an index of words and it gives their context. Wherever they may appear. So if I was looking for "the" it would be like    "the" : pg 199, 1, 2, 3 etc. Sometimes they give a short paragraph like "THE leaf on a branch."

Answer (score 1):

First of all - why are you using some weird classes like:

- SET
- ST

instead of built-in java classes:

- Set
- Map

Which are nedded here?

As for your problem, your code should not compile at all since you are declaring the variable `inv` AFTER using it:

```
public static String[] invertConcordance (ST<String, SET<Integer>> st) {

 //This is what I have so far
//Here is what I have that doesnt work
for(String key : st.keys())
{
inv[i++] = key;
}
for(int z = 0; z< inv.length; z++)
{
System.out.println(inv[z]);
}


 String[]inv = new String[st.size()];

    return inv;
}
```

If I understand your idea correctly, the concordances simply creates the list of words and sets containing indices on which there were found. If this is a correct interpretation then an inverse operation would be:

```
public static String[] invertConcordance (ST<String, SET<Integer>> st) {

//First - figure out the length of the document, which is simply the maximum index in the concordancer
int document_length = 0;
for(String key : st.keys()){
  for(Integer i : st.get(key)){
    if(i>document_length){
      document_length=i;
    }
  }
}    

//Create the document
String[] document = new String[document_length+1];

//Reconstruct
for(String key : st.keys()){
  for(Integer i : st.get(key)){
    document[i] = key;
  }
}

return document;
}
```

I assumed, that indices are numbered from 0 to the document's length-1, if there are actually stored from the 1 to document'length you should modify lines:

```
String[] document = new String[document_length+1];
```

to

```
String[] document = new String[document_length];
```

and

```
    document[i] = key;
```

to

```
    document[i-1] = key;
```